# HTML5 Range Type Controller Styling

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm doing a custom slider with the new

```
<input type="range">
```

So far I've got [this JsFiddle working](https://jsfiddle.net/1hgko8q3/)

Which is great.
I'm trying to figure out how I can color the areas of the slider that has been passed.

Such that the slider has a default color:
[image: Slider at zero value]

But when it's in the center the passed half is another color, like so:

[image: Slider progress]

and when the slider is at the max value, it should be just that one color:

[image: Slider at max]

Does anyone know how I can tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: check this codepen  http://codepen.io/nl_fonseca/pen/MwbovQ

Comment: Thanks Qwal! That worked out for me :)